# Fantasy book with a man and woman; the man is being "trained" by the bad guy but it's really the girl who has magic

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

Read a book a while back. Can't remember title or author, only some of the plot.

There was a girl with magic; she meets a man after leaving her village, I believe. She then draws the attention of the antagonist, a wizard who thinks it's the guy who has magic. They pretend it is the guy, and while the wizard "trains" the guy, the girl does the magic. The bad guy finds out in the end that it's the girl with magic after the guy accidently falls asleep during a "lesson".

Read it in high school so about 2009-2012; i think its older published in late 90s early 2000s.

Regards to cover: I remember just old school castle or mansion kinda not unique

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Read it in high school so about 2009-2012; i think its older published in late 90s early 2000s

Comment: Regards to cover: I remember just old school castle or mansion kinda not unique

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is Dawn Cook's *[First Truth](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/111022.First_Truth)* as per [Trying to remember a book involving a girl from a distrusted race becoming a mage and a dragon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76496/trying-to-remember-a-book-involving-a-girl-from-a-distrusted-race-becoming-a-mag).

[image: Front cover of First Truth]

> Alissa doesn't believe in magic. Her father's stories about the Hold, a legendary fortress where human Keepers learn magic from the enigmatic Maters, are just that―stories. But her mother insists that Alissa has inherited her father's magical ability, and so she must go to the Hold―the only place her talents can be trained.
>
> On her way, she crosses paths with Strell, a wandering musician from the plains. And though Alissa is not sure she can trust a plainsman, Strell has something she needs―one of her father's old maps. Travelling together, they can reach the Hold before the snow sets in.
>
> But they don't know that the Hold is nearly empty. Something is very wrong and someone believes that Alissa and Strell knows about a book called *First Truth*.

I believe that when they arrive, Alissa lets Bailic believe that Strell is the one with the talent. Unfortunately, I don't remember if they do have a plotline where he's found out because he falls asleep, but I do remember there is a scene where he essentially hypnotizes Alissa to try to get the truth from her (it's foiled by the trapped dragon taking over for her) and when she awakes, she sees Strell asleep, and realizes that they don't have long before Bailic realizes that she is indeed the person with the magic.

Comment: Hi thanks for all this. I looked up the book and looked through the book and it is not the one I was thinking of. But it is now added to my to read list.

Comment: @SDZ: Are there any differences that you can note in your question other than possibly there not being a scene where the boy falls asleep during training?