# A book about a girl longing for the sky who later can transform into a dragon

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for a book where it begins with a girl longing for the sky at nights. Her dad went away but she still remembers him fondly. At one point she goes out to find her dad but only finds an empty castle/fortress and over time it turns out that she, like her dad, can transform into a dragon. However, this is not without risk and the transformation is risky because she can be lost to the beast.

I also remember that the author was named Cook, but it was an Alias for someone else. The book series had three parts but all were not that long.

I read the book around 2015 and I got it from a library in my hometown (and read the books at home). It seemed to be a little older. The Covers had a circle on them and where colored green, purple and I don't remember the last color, maybe orange, but all similar composition.

For more about the story: As the girl fled from the house to find the dad (and leave the mom behind) she finds the fortress, but no one except one man is there. It turns out all of the other dragons were missing including her dad. While at first the man seems friendly it turns out he is involved with the vanishing of the other dragons. I think it ends somehow with the idea that she will continue the legacy of these dragons who can transform back and forth into their human form and try to educate other person-dragons to fulfill the transformation and not fall to the beast.

I also remember that she falls to the beast inside temporarily. She also gets thrown into a prison where one side is open to the cliffs, but she can't flee as she does not trust her beast side. The beast in the dragon and the human can communicate internally and they work together ("tame the beast") at the end (I think others wanted her to suppress it, but she refuses as letting the beast fly is way more fun, so she makes a deal with it)

I think the authors name was Crook

Comment: When did you read it? Where were you when you read it. Did you read it in English? How old do you think the book was (was it new when you read it, or older? How much older at a guess?) Can you describe the cover, or any other elements you can remember from the story?

Comment: @BinaryWorrier I extended the description a lot, hope this helps!

Comment: I searched Amazon and found a fantasy author named Jeff Crook

Comment: Jeff Crook's works are listed here. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Crook

Comment: You are probably familiar with the process from Stack Overflow, but your question has been marked as Duplicate. It is not a censure, but more of a bookkeeping thing that we do in a particular way with [tag:story-identification] questions that share an answer. You will still receive points for upvotes, and people can comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[First Truth](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6651103-first-truth)* by Dawn Cook (aka [Kim Harrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Harrison)) as per [Trying to remember a book involving a girl from a distrusted race becoming a mage and a dragon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76496/trying-to-remember-a-book-involving-a-girl-from-a-distrusted-race-becoming-a-mag)

> Alissa doesn't believe in magic. Her father's stories about the Hold, a legendary fortress where human Keepers learn magic from the enigmatic Maters, are just that―stories. But her mother insists that Alissa has inherited her father's magical ability, and so she must go to the Hold―the only place her talents can be trained.
>
> On her way, she crosses paths with Strell, a wandering musician from the plains. And though Alissa is not sure she can trust a plainsman, Strell has something she needs―one of her father's old maps. Travelling together, they can reach the Hold before the snow sets in.
>
> But they don't know that the Hold is nearly empty. Something is very wrong and someone believes that Alissa and Strell knows about a book called First Truth.

Alissa learns to turn into a "raku", a dragon in the series world. And I do believe that there was a plot line, if not in the first book, that she could get stuck in that form if she stayed there too long.

Comment: This is exactly it! Thank you very very much!

Comment: :-D As you can probably see from the linked question, I was looking for it myself a few years ago. Good news, there are multiple books, although I think I petered out somewhere around the third one.

Comment: Yeah sadly they are kinda hard to find here in Germany it seems.

Comment: The plot line about being stuck as raku happens in the last book, and the danger is not in staying too long. Instead, being a raku means having a beast mind in addition to the human one, and the danger is the beast mind may take over. And of course our dear Alissa doesn't care about the rules about handling the beast mind safely ... :)